# Weak-keyed dictionary in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, weak-references

I'm wondering if it's possible to have something similar to ActionScript 3's `Dictionary` object with weak keys in Objective-C. I want to be able to 'attach' an instance of a class to other arbitrary instances.

Example;

```
MetaData *meta = [MetaData metaDataForObject:someObject];
meta.whatever = foo;
```

And later:

```
foo = [MetaData metaDataForObject:someObject].whatever;
[foo doStuff];
```

The tricky part is that after the objected referenced by `someObject` is dealloc'd, I want the object referenced by `meta` to be released (and dealloc'd, assuming no client code has retained it).

Possible? I took a look at `+[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]` but I'm not sure if this is what I want because there when I later query `-[NSValue nonretainedObjectValue]` it seems like I would get a pointer to garbage (how could NSValue zero the pointer when the object was dealloc'd?).

Thanks,

benjamin

**Update 23 September 2011:** I believe the way to do this is with `objc_setAssociatedObject` and related functions. See the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking for is the ability to react to a weak-referenced instance variable being deallocated.  You can certainly use the `__weak` attribute (with GC enabled) to create a weak reference, but there's no built-in mechanism to catch when such an attribute is zeroed after its target is GCed.

If you really want this, your best bet is to use the same mechanism Apple's Key-Value Observing uses: method swizzling.  Maintain a global table (such as a `NSHashMap` or `NSMapTable`) mapping objects to their corresponding metadata objects, then replace the `dealloc`/`finalize` methods in the class of the object you're attaching to with versions that look up the corresponding metadata object in the table and send a message to tear it down.  (You also need another table or two that maps classes to their original `dealloc`/`finalize` methods.)  [JRSwizzle](http://rentzsch.com/trac/wiki/JRSwizzle) provides a nice interface to swizzling.

If you want to to be really fancy, instead of overwriting the `dealloc`/`finalize` for all objects of the target class, you can create a proxy class and reassign the `isa` pointer for just that class, such that there's no performance hit on deallocation for the objects you're not watching.  (KVO does this, too.)

Comment: Method swizzling sounds pretty straight-forward. Can you elaborate on the isa-swizzling technique you mentioned? As I understand it, that would allow me to effectively change the class of the object, thereby providing a new implementation of <code>dealloc</code>, correct?

Comment: Also note that in 10.5 there is a function you can use for this, which is preferable going forward: http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_setClass

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [NSHashMap](http://chanson.livejournal.com/176390.html) perhaps?  It does zeroing references.

Comment: I'm developing for iPhone and unfortunately NSHashMap doesn't seem to be available.