# iphone memory management

Tags: iphone

1.UIImageView *img1=[[UIImageView alloc]initwithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];

2.UIImageView *img2=[[UIImageView alloc]initwithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];

a) img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];

```
b) [img1 setImage:img2];
```

which way utilizes minimum memory among  a and b?why?

if i need to do this multiple times which way you suggest?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is very close to duplicating the question just asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867945/memory-issue-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

b) Because you are creating a reference to an existing object, but they will both point to "2.png"  In a) you are creating a new instance of an object which coincidentally happens to point to the same file, but it is allocated as separate memory space.