# Adding Garbage Collection to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

MonoTouch has automatic garbage collection on the iPhone. **Couldn't someone prematurely implement garbage collection for Objective-C on iOS?** I'm not the guy to do it, but I'm curious as to why or whether this is impossible.

I know that projects like [this](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) exist: what does it take to use them on iOS? Since they are in C/C++ anyway, and Objective-C contains those languages as subsets, but yet, those languages are actually aware of the system architecture... I'm out of my depths here...

**While we're here, if anyone knows of any attempts to implement a GC on iOS, links would be helpful...**

Comment: I also really care about this question, how does MonoTouch do it? Is it good enough, battery life, performance ...

Comment: Hi @vodkhang: short answer is they, um, implement it in code. Long answer is I-don't-know but also there-are-standard-algorithms-for-this. How is battery-life, performance: not sure. It's not as good as "native" apps, perhaps, but then they DO get accepted to the store, that's for sure. And if it's good enough for Apple, it's good enough for me.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about it, but wouldn't it make sense for Apple to include Garbage Collection in a future iOS version?

Comment: @DysonApps: I think sooner or later, it will be added when you have powerful enough processing and long enough battery life. I also think about the pressure on Android will force Apple doing more

Comment: yeah, I think if it is good enough for Apple, that will be good enough for a lot of people:)

Comment: @vodkhang this conversation is so 2010! Now we have ARC and aside from having to completely understand retain-release, still, the developer is free to not think about memory management except maybe 75% of the time. So easy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. The problem is that Objective-C is used inside the system library too. In OS X where garbage-collected Objective-C is supported, there are in fact three modes when you compile a code:

1. the function compiled can be only called from non-GC environment.
2. the function compiled can be only called from GC environment.
3. the function compiled can be called both from GC and non-GC environment.

See the discussion [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/Articles/gcEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002452-SW6), for example.  The point is that the system library needs to be in the third mode in order for the OS to support both non-GC and GC apps. And in OS X, the libraries come in this hybrid mode. In iOS, I guess it comes in the mode 1. (I don't know for sure because I haven't jailbroken my phone, though.)

If you have complete control over both the system library and your app, it's possible to make them all garbage collected, but unfortunately we're not in that stage yet.

I'm sure we'll have GC in iOS in two years.

Comment: This is basically the dealbreaker. I don't imagine it would even be too hard to port the OS X libauto garbage collector to the iPhone, but it would be useless because the system libraries wouldn't support it.

Comment: Also, the garbage collector on the Mac works reasonably well because it can collect on a background thread.  On a multicore machine (all shipping Macs for a while now) this can run without interfering with the performance of the main application.  We don't yet have multicore iOS devices, so I'd expect this only after they come out.

Comment: Thanks @Yuji, @Chuck, @Brad Larson.... I kind of guessed that it mustn't be easy otherwise it would already exist as a third-party lib. How ironic that the MonoTouch guys get a GC (even for framework classes, I think) and in obj-c we don't.

Comment: @Chuck, @Brad, you also need to tell the compiler's ARM backend to generate write barriers...

Comment: @Yar MonoTouch needs to bridge C# and Objective-C. The GC is taken care of when C# objects are translated to Objective-C objects; it's part of what they need to do anyway. If you're sufficiently industrious, you can write a compiler of "Objective-C with GC" down to "Objective-C without GC", just as MonoTouch is a compiler from "C# with GC" down to "Objective-C without GC". This way you can circumvent the problem that the system library doesn't support GC. The compiler `clang` is open-sourced, so you can do that if you'd like :)

Comment: @Yuji, thanks, I'll keep that as a theoretical possibility for now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stops you from building your own garbage collector for your app. Or importing another project that will handle it. Again, for your app.

more discussion:

[Is garbage collection supported for iPhone applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416108/is-garbage-collection-supported-for-iphone-applications)

Comment: Thanks. I was kind of hoping for some links to how to do it, not more information on how to work with retain/release. I've already got my brown belt on retain/release.

Comment: good point. I definitely read your question as more about philosophy than implementation. I think most of the replies you'll get are going to be the former rather than the latter. Anyway, it shouldn't take much to add one of the c/c++ gc, I would think. I think you can probably just start using them in your project without any special preparation.

Comment: Thanks, the question was probably worded for the cafe I was sitting in when I wrote it, so you're right. I should try this, I guess, but I have no idea how a GC would play with the objective-c ref counting stuff.

Comment: it probably wouldnt. you'd need the whole thing to be completely disjoint.